# php query ends with HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code page ---

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();
include 'config.php';

$uid=$_GET['uid'];
$_SESSION['uid']=$uid;

$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select profile_pic from cae_users_picture where email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($profile_pic);
$stmt->fetch();

$stmt2 = $linkID1->prepare("select fullname,user_type from cae_users where email=?");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $uid);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($fullname,$user_type);
$stmt2->fetch();
?>
```

when i am accessing the page using url -
http://www.mywebsitename.com/mypagename.php?uid=ravikumar@gmail.com

Then i am getting the following error

> This page isn’t working
>
> www.mywebsitename.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Pls help. Whats wrong in the php code.

Comment: @Arun....Thnx for editing the question

Comment: Who is giving -1 vote. What more research u want. If u can't help then don't give random votes also

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution myself. just added ---

```
$stmt->close();
$stmt2->close();
```

after both the queries.
And the page is now working fine.